# How can SVN Authorization be done with a LDAP group

Tags: svn, ldap, authorization, ldap-client

I am trying to set up LDAP based authorization for svn repos as the number of developers is quite a long number. Rather than putting the users manually in the authz file it should query the ldap and fetch the users from a particular group. How can this be done. 
Help is much appreciated